# Where is my app.config file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have built a server api that consists aith 3 projects:
Api(an api project) that calles BL(class library) that calls Dal(class library).
Very standard.
It works perfectly locally.
Now when I publish it, the app.config of the BL disappears.
Why is it? Where can I store my configurable parameters?
Thank you very much. Tal

Comment: In MVC you should use `web.config` for  configurable parameters

Comment: configurable parameters? Did you mean `appsettings`? You can not get appsetting from BL and Dal library in your mvc project.

Answer (score 1):

On your main project ASP.NET, use the `Web.Config` instead of `App.Config` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

app.config is only the name during development, once the project is built the app.config is copied to .config and this is what is used by the application when running

An asp.net application reads config from web.config so if you have an app.config it implies that your project is not a web project but a standard library or executable.

if it is a library (.dll) then you should place your config in the web.config (if the library is used by asp.net) or in the .config if its a standard executable.

Ideally your libraries should not read settings as this creates a hidden coupling between the library and config files, and it would be better to provide those configuration parameters to the classes that need them in the library externally, this then leaves the application using the library free to store them where ever is most appropriate.

How is the consumer of your library going to know that they need to add SettingX to the appsettings of their configuration file? Better for the library to require the setting value directly. So if your DAL needs a connection string then the class which wants a connection string should ask for it in their constructor. Then the application using it can get it from settings (or whereever) and pass it to the library., and the consumers have visibility of the dependency on the connection string. If the library reads it from config the consumer has no way to know that this is something they need add to the settings

So in a web app the startup would read the settings from web.config and pass them to your library but some other app using the same library could store them in a database if they wanted.

Comment: I can see that I am not getting to you.  The problem is that in my class library BL I use appSetting, in order to make these parameter configurable. now I publish the whole server side, which is my part of the project. The BL uses the parameters I inserted to the Appsettings, but I can't find where to change it if needed, which was the whole point in using app setting, like I do when I am programing stuff that is not web api.

Comment: @tal I understand your problem, but it seems that you do not understand how configuration in .net works. The app.config file **is never read** by anything. This is just a design time file. The file that is used to read settings from is based on the name of the currently executing program by default (or web.config for a asp.net program), so unless you are changing the config file to use in the library code it will be looking for your settings in the web.config. I suggest that you read up how config works and then reread my answer to see if it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Thank you sam, I will do that. Actually I do know that, Is is just that I am used to Dll.Config files been created, and I could not understand what replaces it on a web project. I get it now. Thank you again,